# JavaScript - Asynchronous request issue

Tags: javascript

A common Asynchronous request is made by the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:1337/test.php", true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            abc = xhr.responseText;
        } else {
            console.error(xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
};
a = JSON.parse(abc);
```

I get the following error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined`

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Move `a = JSON.parse(abc);` in the `xhr.onload` success/OK condition. Also see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call abc outside onload that might be the only issue.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:1337/test.php", true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var abc = xhr.responseText;
                var a = JSON.parse(abc); // moved it here  
            } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
```

> to return value from a function, Use it this way

```
function getResult(myFunction) {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:1337/test.php", true);
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    var abc = xhr.responseText;
                    myFunction(abc);
                } else {
                    console.error(xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
}

function myFunction(jsonData) {
 //do whatever you wish to do here
}
```

> Now how you are going to call it.

```
getResult(myFunction); //callback;
```

Comment: I actually need the abc variable to have the return value outside the onload function because I am doing some further parsing on the JSON object

Comment: You need to think asynchronously then

Comment: can you please explain @Jaromanda X

Comment: see the links already posted on the reason this is a duplicate question, and in the comment by Tushar

Comment: I modified the answer as per your requirement, hope it helps